# Maximum value in a filter/slice of a pivot table in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How to set automatic selection of the maximum value in a slice of a pivot table in Google Sheets?
I want a pivot table filter or slicer to select automatically the maximum value found in column B (Date). In Excel, I have implemented this using a macro, but how to implement this in Google Sheets?

Tried filtering by condition: `=Date=MAX('Table'!B2:B)` . It did not help.
I tried to place the formula `=MAX('Table'!B2:B)` in a separate cell (for example, C1) and write in the filter `=Date=C1` - that didn't help either.